# Validation in dropdown goes wrong in ASP.Net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a login page, but whenever I typed wrong credentials it showing the mainheader for login person but with no name.. See the image I attached for further explanations

login
[image: login page]

login with wrrong credentials
[image: not login but showed the main bar for login person]
[image]

this is what it look like when the person login successfully, it have name and company
[image]

View form

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
@{
     AccountContactVM customer = (AccountContactVM)ViewBag.AccountData;
 }
 @if (customer.User == customer.User && customer.User != null )
 {
     <li class="dropdown">
         <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
             <i class="fa fa-user-circle fa-fw fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"</i>
             @customer.User.FirstName @customer.User.LastName
             <span class="caret"></span>
         </a>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                 <li class="disabled">
                     <div class="row">
                         <div class="col-md-3">
                             <i class="fa fa-user-circle" style="font-size:40px;padding:5px 20px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-md-9">
                             <p style="padding-top:5px;">
                                 @customer.User.FirstName @customer.User.LastName 
                             <br />
                                 @customer.Company.AccountName
                             </p>                   
                         </div>
                     </div>   
                 </li>
                 <li class="divider"></li>
                 <li><a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Index">Customer Portal</a></li>
                 <li class="divider"></li>
                 <li><a a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="LogOut">Logout</a></li>
             </ul>
         </li>
     }
     else
     {
         <li><a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignUp">Register</a></li>
         <li><a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn"><i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>Login</a></li>
     }
     <li ng-cloak><a href="@Url.Action("Index","Cart")"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></i>Cart(<strong>{{CartCount}}</strong>)</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: can you please remove customer.User == customer.User from if condition there is no meaning of this condition and put if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(customer.user))

Comment: argument cannot convert from model to string, so I put .tostring() but I'm having now a an error an unhandled exception

Comment: you can use Convert.Tostring() instead of toString()

Comment: contact does not contain Convert

Comment: please check this one @if(customer.user != string.empty && customer.user !=null)

Comment: still the canoot convert contacts to string, so i put .tostring but getting the error

Comment: you can only check null value means @if(customer.user !=null){ } because if object does not have empty value only contain value or null

Comment: Yes, I already know that now I'm trying to resolve if it is wrong credentials